# Phonegap native notification sounds

Tags: cordova, audio, push-notification, ionic-framework

Is there any way to use the native/default notification sounds in Phonegap for notifications (particularly the PushPlugin for phonegap)? Currently it DOES use my default notification sound, however, I would like to add the option to customize the notification sound to use any of the default sounds already on the phone.

Is this possible? If so, how can I achieve it for iOS and Android?

FYI I am using Ionic for my app.

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at this : https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/pull/421

Comment: This too: https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/pull/301

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import java.io.IOException;

String soundName = extras.getString("sound");
if (soundName != null) {
    MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
    AssetFileDescriptor file;
    try {
        file = getAssets().openFd("www/sounds/"+soundName+".mp3");
        player.setDataSource(file.getFileDescriptor(), file.getStartOffset(), file.getLength());
        defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        mBuilder.setDefaults(defaults);
        player.prepare();
        player.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
}

mNotificationManager.notify((String) appName, notId, mBuilder.build());
```

Sourced from [here](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/pull/421/files)

Answer (score 0):

You can try my [phonegap-push plugin](https://github.com/HainaAlfonso/phonegap-push-ringtone) but this is for android only. You can control the vibration, sound, light and the ringtone in this plugin. Just use  `PushNotification.showPushSettings()` after the device is ready and it will pop up a window.

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged on StackOverflow. Please, try to add as much content as possible into your answer.